# Image for all WinJS controls list

Tags: windows-8, controls, winjs

Frankly speaking I am not sure if this is the right question for this forum. If its not, feel free to point me as to where to post it. I am just looking for an image that has all the controls provided by WinJS (e.g., rating, toggle switch, list view, flip view etc). On MSDN I find places where it list all controls (like [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465453.aspx)) but not an image that shows all these controls. May be I am not using right keywords during my google search. Anyone has any links for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may not be an exhaustive list, but one of the presentations of the [Windows 8 Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29854) includes a Windows 8 UI presentation where many (all?) of the widgets are covered.  When you download, it's in the Presentations\05 - UI Controls folder.  Here's one of the slides to give you a feel of what's there:

[image]